# Mouse pad not working in Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-12.04

I got a new Dell lap top, and it worked fine for some time, but I think system update did something wrong to the mouse driver. The mouse is no longer showing. 
I used to be able to fix it with:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Not working anymore. 
What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too when I bought Dell with Ubuntu 12.04 it is not a problem with laptop.
It is the problem in Ubuntu after updating or moving to other version.

You can try out some commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

but it will work only for that session to make it permanent, you should save a configuration file, like:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

you name anything you want.
and type

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

It should work for you, if not please let me know.

2. Method 
Install dconf editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

and go to start menu, find it and open it.

Navigate to the path `org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad`
and tick the box :`touchpad-enabled`

Sorry I can't guide you through the images.

Comment: touchpad-indicator didn't do the trick. Any other suggestions?